# Map " Internal Name" and "External User Visible Name" in Real-Time Collaboration Time Zones in Oracle

Tags: javascript, oracle, perl, timezone, cpan

Please Refer this link,
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13866_04/webconf.904/b10877/timezone.htm

I have timezone values from 
http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-TimeZone/lib/DateTime/TimeZone/Catalog.pm
which is in the format of "Internal Name" provided by Oracle. I want to show "External User Visible Name" of Oracle instead of these to Users. Is there any Mapping Module or way to achieve this?

Is there any support from oracle to map "Internal Name" and "External User Visible Name" for TimeZones?

Is there any CPAN module which will do the same thing in Perl?

If nothing is there like that, then I am more interested in finding the alternative for the "External Names". Any standard Name format with "UTC value" and Name which can be mapped to "Internal Oracle Names".

**Example :**
In Microsoft windows 7, Change Date Time Settings -> TimeZone .

***(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) -> America/Los_Angeles***

Here we have TimeZone Name in Right and desired Name in Left.